# when I use useDispatch inside useEffect my component keep rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

When I use dispatch as follows in my react component, My component keeps rendering. How can I avoid that?

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(reportsActionCreators.changeSalesDashboardData(someData));
  }, []);
```

in the parent component, I'm using useSelector as this. But didn't use this report's data.

```
  const { selectedSalesTab } = useSelector<RootState, any>((state: RootState) => {
  return {
    selectedSalesTab: state.reports.selectedSalesTab,
  };
```

this is the parent component I'm using.

```
const SalesReports: FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { selectedSalesTab } = useSelector<RootState, any>((state: RootState) => {
    return {
      selectedSalesTab: state.reports.selectedSalesTab,
    };
  });

  const getPageContent = useMemo(() => {
    switch (selectedSalesTab) {
      case salesReportsTabs[0].id:
        return <Dashboard />;
      default:
        return <div>not found :(</div>;
    }
  }, [selectedSalesTab]);

  return (
    <div className="sales-report-wrapper">
      <GTTabs
        id="sales-reports-tabs"
        onClickTab={(tab: Tab) => dispatch(reportsActionCreators.changeSalesTab(tab.id))}
        tabs={salesReportsTabs}
        defaultSelectedTabId={selectedSalesTab}
      />
      <div>{getPageContent}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SalesReports;
```

this is the Child component I'm using

```
const Dashboard: FC = () => {
  const repostsRxjs = rxjsConfig(reportingAxios);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    repostsRxjs
      .post<SalesDashboardItem[]>(
        '/sales-data/order-details/6087bc3606ff073930a10848?timezone=Asia/Dubai&from=2022-09-03T00:00:00.00Z&to=2022-12-25T00:00:00.00Z&size=10',
        {
          brandIds: [],
          channelIds: [],
          kitchenIds: [],
          countryIds: [],
        },
      )
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        catchError((err: any) => of(console.log(err))),
      )
      .subscribe((response: SalesDashboardItem[] | void) => {
        if (response) {
          dispatch(reportsActionCreators.changeSalesDashboardData(response));
        }
      });
  }, []);

  const { isActiveFilter } = useSelector<RootState, any>((state: RootState) => {
    return {
      isActiveFilter: state.filterData.isActiveFilter,
    };
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch(filterssActionCreators.handleFilterPanel(!isActiveFilter));
          dispatch(
            filterssActionCreators.changeSelectedFiltersType([
              FilterTypes.BRAND,
              FilterTypes.CHANNEL,
              FilterTypes.COUNTRY,
              FilterTypes.KITCHEN,
            ]),
          );
        }}
      >
        Dashboard
      </div>
      {isActiveFilter && <FilterPanel />}
    </>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Actions

```
  import { SalesDashboardItem } from 'app/models/Reports';
import { actionCreator } from 'app/state/common';

export type ChangeSalesTabPayload = string;
export type ChangeSalesDashboardDataPayload = SalesDashboardItem[];

export const reportsActionTypes = {
  CHANGE_SALES_TAB: 'CHANGE_SALES_TAB',
  CHANGE_SALES_DASHABOARD_DATA: 'CHANGE_SALES_DASHABOARD_DATA',
};

export const reportsActionCreators = {
  changeSalesTab: actionCreator<ChangeSalesTabPayload>(reportsActionTypes.CHANGE_SALES_TAB),
  changeSalesDashboardData: actionCreator<ChangeSalesDashboardDataPayload>(
    reportsActionTypes.CHANGE_SALES_DASHABOARD_DATA,
  ),
};

export type ReportsAction = {
  type: typeof reportsActionTypes.CHANGE_SALES_TAB | typeof reportsActionTypes.CHANGE_SALES_DASHABOARD_DATA;
  payload: ChangeSalesTabPayload | ChangeSalesDashboardDataPayload;
};
```

Reducer

```
    import { SalesDashboardItem } from 'app/models/Reports';
import { salesReportsTabs } from 'app/utils/reports';
import { reportsActionTypes, ReportsAction } from './actions';

export type ReportsState = {
  selectedSalesTab: string;
  salesDashboardFilterData: {
    brands: string[];
    kitchens: string[];
    channels: string[];
    countries: string[];
  };
  salesDashBoardDatta: SalesDashboardItem[];
};

const initialState: ReportsState = {
  selectedSalesTab: salesReportsTabs[0].id,
  salesDashboardFilterData: {
    brands: [],
    kitchens: [],
    channels: [],
    countries: [],
  },
  salesDashBoardDatta: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action: ReportsAction): ReportsState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case reportsActionTypes.CHANGE_SALES_TAB:
      return { ...state, selectedSalesTab: action.payload as string };
    case reportsActionTypes.CHANGE_SALES_DASHABOARD_DATA:
      return { ...state, salesDashBoardDatta: action.payload as SalesDashboardItem[] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

root reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import SidePanelReducer from './reducers/sidepanel.reducer';
import authReducer from './auth';
import onboardingReducer from './onboarding';
import applicationReducer from './application';
import inventoryConfigReducer from './inventoryConfig/inventory.reducer';
import reportsReducer from './reports';
import filtersReducer from './filter';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  sidePanel: SidePanelReducer,
  auth: authReducer,
  onboarding: onboardingReducer,
  application: applicationReducer,
  inventory: inventoryConfigReducer,
  reports: reportsReducer,
  filterData: filtersReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

when I'm adding the dispatch action in useEffect(componentDidMount) this looping is happening. Otherwise, this code works fine. How can I avoid that component rerendering?

Comment: probebly parent compnent is rerendering child base on redux state changes

Comment: Do you mean something in the app is render looping, or you've dispatched the action and the app rerenders a few times? Can you [edit] the post to include more relevant details and a more complete [mcve] that includes the code for this component and the redux code?

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh in parent component I'm using use Selector as this

  const { selectedSalesTab } = useSelector<RootState, any>((state: RootState) => {
    return {
      selectedSalesTab: state.reports.selectedSalesTab,
    };
  });

will this be the issue?

Comment: might be , I recommand use react memo and see if it works https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_memo.asp

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh Better to link to [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh I'm using useMemo to render the child component

Comment: that's right but that was much more easier to understand @DrewReese

Comment: aha ok, could you please provide some more information or make a codesandbox for it @supunrajasinghe

Comment: @DrewReese Ah yes It's continuously looping the child component.

Comment: Ok, then certainly an issue exists. Seems the child component is remounting. Can you edit to include complete component code examples? Parent/child, and the redux code (action, reducer, etc).

Comment: @DrewReese I have inserted the parent and child components

Comment: @DrewReese I have attached action and reducer files too. Can you please check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the `useSelector` hook is returning a new object reference each time which triggers the `useMemo` hook to re-memoize an "instance" of the `Dashboard` component. The new "instance" of `Dashboard` then mounts and runs its `useEffect` hook which dispatches an action that updates the `state.reports` state in the Redux store.

Instead of creating and returning a new object reference to destructure `selectedSalesTab` from, just return the `state.reports` object directly.

Change

```js
const { selectedSalesTab } = useSelector<RootState, any>((state: RootState) => {
  return {
    selectedSalesTab: state.reports.selectedSalesTab,
  };
});
```

to

```js
const { selectedSalesTab } = useSelector<RootState, any>((state: RootState) => {
  return state.reports;
});
```

Comment: I change the code as above, But Still child component rerendering @DrewReese

Comment: @supunrajasinghe Hmm, ok, perhaps other issues exist. Could you try making a *minimal, running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of this code that reproduces the rendering issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Sure, I'll add,

Comment: I have added some code examples in codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-redux-brozhz

in there this is working I guess.

in my project, I removed the useSelector in the parent component and tried. But the parent component still rerendering. And also this rendering happens only when I use dispatch inside useEffect. If this dispatch thing used in inside onClick function this is not happenning

Comment: @supunrajasinghe Maybe the issue is triggered further upstream in the app. Can you edit the sandbox to include more of your code, a component at-a-time, to see if you can eventually reproduce the render looping issue?

Comment: I found the issue bro, In my routing component I have used useSelector as in my child component. That is the issue. I changed it as you answer. Now It's working. You are a life savior bro. Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: @supunrajasinghe Ok, glad it's all working now. Cheers and good luck!.